# How to send broadcast intent from instrumentation test

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, automated-tests

There are two applications which are run in background and communicate with each other using broadcast intents. Now, I need to create some instrumentation tests to cover communication functionality on device.

In tests I need, for example, to send a specific broadcast intent and check that broadcast receiver got it (compare got intent type in broadcast receiver with sent one, etc.)

The problem is that when I try to **send broadcast**, **register broadcast receiver**, etc. in `@Test`, I got:

> cannot resolve method 'registerReceiver(com...MyBroadcastReceiver, com.content.IntentFilter) '
>
> cannot resolve method 'sendBroadcast(com.content.Intent) '
>
> ...

What should I do to be able to use such functionality in instrumentation tests? Should test classes be inherited from some specific classes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`registerReceiver()` and `sendBroadcast()` are both methods of `Context`, so you'll need a `Context` instance to call them.

Take a look at the [`InstrumentationRegistry`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html) class.

Use its static `getTargetContext()` method to get ahold of the `Context` (so you can call your receiver methods on that instance).

For example:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().sendBroadcast(someIntent);
```

Comment: Looks like even in tests the ban on implicit intents is in effect. https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html This pattern no longer works for me on O+ devices

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your tests in Android API 26 or higher `Context.sendBroadcast` won't work. More information about broadcasts limitations [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#changes-system-broadcasts).

From android docs:

> The `LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast` method sends broadcasts to receivers that are in the same app as the sender. If you don't need to send broadcasts across apps, use local broadcasts.

This is how you can use `LocalBroadcastManager` in your instrumentation tests:

```
 val broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context)
 broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent)
```